# Запретить движение в противоположном направлении

Tags: c#, unity3d

Игра "ЗМЕЙКА" крашится если нажать на кнопку движения в противоположную сторону, как пофиксить?
Как изменить код, чтобы после нажатия "вверх" нельзя было поменять направление на "вниз", а
после нажатия "влево" нельзя было поменять направление на "вправо" и наоборот.

```
private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
        {
            _direction = Vector2.up;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
        {
            _direction = Vector2.down;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            _direction = Vector2.left;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
        {
            _direction = Vector2.right;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
private void Update()
{
     SetDirection();
}

private void SetDirection() 
{
    var newDirection = Vector2.zero;
    
    var axisX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    var axisY = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    
    if (axisY > 0.5)
        newDirection = Vector2.up;
    else if (axisY < -0.5)
        newDirection = Vector2.down;
    else if (axisX > 0.5)
        newDirection = Vector2.right;
    else if (axisX < -0.5)
        newDirection = Vector2.left;
    else return;

    if (_direction != -newDirection)
        _direction = newDirection;
}
```

---

PS Код писался вслепую и могут быть какие-то логические или синтаксические ошибки.

Comment: да, дошло ______

Comment: дописал, чтобы код отвечал на вопрос

Comment: @Andrew  Со скобками не могу разобраться, не распознает последний if

Comment: @Andrew Что означают эти цифры 0.5? Змейка крашится если отпустить клавишу направления, приходится ее постоянно держать нажатой

Comment: @aepot ваше мнение тоже хочется услышать, что не так с этими осями, почему мой ответ работает как надо, хоть только для клавиш WASD,  а этот нет?

Comment: @y3x3la исправил ошибку в коде.

Comment: @aepot отлично, все работает, только значения поменял на 0.01, а то приходилось со всей силы нажимать на клавиатуру)

Comment: @y3x3la да, 0.01f это более правильно, как мне кажется. Можно даже 0f попробовать.

Answer (score 2):

```
private void SetDirection (Vector2Int direction) 
{
    if (_direction != -direction)
        _direction = direction;
}
```

Comment: После добавления этого в программу, проблема не решилась

Comment: @y3x3la покажите обновленный код, где проблема не решилась. Ваш комментарий ни о чем не говорит.

Comment: Думаю и так ясно что он просто скопировал метод и все.

Comment: Я предполагал, что нужно добавить эти 5 строк в программу и все заработает

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Update()
    {
        Vector2 direction;

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
            direction = Vector2.up;
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
            direction = Vector2.down;
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
            direction = Vector2.left;
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
            direction = Vector2.right;

         if _direction != -direction {
            _direction = direction
         }
    }
```

Comment: Сделал код по-проще и по-короче. Но все равно он плохой если что - просто потому что не использует `Input.GetAxis(` , а использует `Input.GetKeyDown(`

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Update()
{
    // Only allow turning up or down while moving in the x-axis
    if (direction.x != 0f)
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow)) {
            direction = Vector2.up;
        } else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow)) {
            direction = Vector2.down;
        }
    }
    // Only allow turning left or right while moving in the y-axis
    else if (direction.y != 0f)
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow)) {
            direction = Vector2.right;
        } else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) {
            direction = Vector2.left;
        }
    }
}
```

Код был найден тут:
https://github.com/zigurous/unity-snake-tutorial/wiki#how-do-i-prevent-the-snake-from-turning-in-on-itself

Comment: плохой код. Плохо читается, использует GetKeyDown, куча вложенных ветвлений, глупое "дублирование" стрелок и WASD в то время как Input.GetAxis делает то же самое.... Короче плохой код.

Comment: Чем не устроил мой ответ данный вчера ночью?) Он короче, проще и читабельнее. А делает на 100% то же самое

Comment: @Andrew The name 'Axis' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @Andrew Предположил что это из-за грамматической ошибки `var axisX = Input.GetAxis(Axis.HoriZontal);` но нет

Comment: @Andrew `var axisX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");` тоже не работает

Comment: Документация говорит что работает: https://docs.unity3d.com/2022.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html